# selection sort error with 3 parallel arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, selection-sort, parallel-arrays

Am using 3 parallel arrays and using a selection sort that is to sort by miles in descending order. It does sort in descending order but when for example i enter data in the input file as follows:

- NC 33.9 5
- VA 22.2 0
- etc.

Then the program will print the 'VA' data twice and not display the 'NC' data. 
Parallel arrays not my idea neither is the selection sort. They are required. please help

```
void sortEntries( string initials[], double miles[], int shelters[] )
{
   int top, bottom, i, n;;
   string tempInitials;
   double tempMiles;
   int tempShelters;

   //Selection sorting for initials[]
   n = 14;
   for( top = 0; top < MAX_ENTRIES - 1; top++ )
   {  
      tempInitials = initials[smallest];
      tempMiles = miles[smallest];
      tempShelters = shelters[smalles];
      smallest = top; 
      //Locate smallest number between 1 and MAX_ENTRIES(14)
      for ( i = top; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++ )
      {
         if ( initials[i] < tempMiles )
         {
            tempInitials = initials[i];
            tempMiles = miles[i];
            tempShelters = shelters[i];
            smallest = i;
         }
      }
      initials[top] = initials[smallest];
      miles[top] = miles[smallest];
      shelters[top] = shelters[smallest];
      initials[smallest] = tempInitials;
      miles[smallest] = tempMiles;
      shelters[smallest] = tempShelters;    
   }
```

Comment: First error: You are comparing a string to a double...what?

Comment: Second error: parallel arrays. Use a single array of structs or classes containing the data you want to sort. Poor design, and an open invitation to unnecessary bugs.

Comment: That is what i have been told numerous times. Truth is this is a hw assignment and the teacher has required use of 3 parallel arrays sorted with a selection sort..

Comment: Iv now been able to get it to sort in descending order. but instead if i enter the data in the file out of order. When there is a big number over a smaller number it print the smaller number parallel array twice

Comment: Strange teaching. You don't need the first three assignments in the inner loop. You could do them once at the end, before the current assignments there, using '[smallest]' instead of '[i]' in each case. It would be clearer too. You would then see exactly what the problem is, as I can.